# Getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException using for loop in Blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying out Blazor and I'm getting this exception when I'm trying to load a list of checkboxes using a for loop.

I've created the list here:

```
public List<Month> Months { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            List<Month> months = new List<Month>()
            {
                new Month{MonthId = 0, MonthName = "All Months", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 1, MonthName = "Jan", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 2, MonthName = "Feb", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 3, MonthName = "Mar", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 4, MonthName = "Apr", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 5, MonthName = "May", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 6, MonthName = "Jun", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 7, MonthName = "Jul", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 8, MonthName = "Aug", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 9, MonthName = "Sep", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 10, MonthName = "Oct", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 11, MonthName = "Nov", isMonthChecked = false},
                new Month{MonthId = 12, MonthName = "Dec", isMonthChecked = false}
            };
};

            Months = months.ToList();
            base.OnInitialized();
```

Then, I created the loop in the Blazor component:

```
@{ 
            for (int i = 0; i < @Months.Count(); i++)
            {
            <ul>
                <li><label for="@Months[i].MonthId" id="checkboxLabel">@Months[i].MonthName</label></li>
                <li><InputCheckbox id="@Months[i].MonthId" @bind-Value="@Months[i].isMonthChecked"></InputCheckbox></li>
            </ul>
            }
        }
```

I've stepped through the debugger and it is pulling the correct data, but when it finishes, it gives me the error. If I reduce the count to 12 (should be 13), it works. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: try this:  @Months.Count() - 1;

Comment: That prevents the exception, but it also removes the last month from the view.

Comment: I came up with a temporary fix, just added an additional field the end and just excluded it from the loop. Not the best practice, but it worked

Comment: asp.net is a little quirky with bools... and webassembly might be showing some kind of quirk here... just curious what happens when .isMonthChecked value is left out... still the same?   The other thing that could possibly be exposing a bug is months to Months? case sensitivity quirk maybe?

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well, did the same. Wondering if it has something to do with Blazor because I've done this in MVC with no issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
@for (int j = 0; j < Months.Count; j++)
{
    int i = j;  // a local copy to solve the capture problem

    <ul>
        <li><label for="@Months[i].MonthId" id="checkboxLabel">@Months[i].MonthName</label></li>
        <li><InputCheckbox id="@Months[i].MonthId" @bind-Value="@Months[i].isMonthChecked"></InputCheckbox></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Which means this is a new, Blazor specific variation on ['capturing the loop variable'](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/).

When you look at the `<pagename>.razor.g.cs` file you can see that the checkbox requires two lambda's, here is a snippet:

```
 __value => Months[i].isMonthChecked = __value
```

and after the for-loop, when the RenderTree is being built,  the value of `i` will be Count for all months.

Using `Count()-1` in the original code (your temporary fix) will prevent the exception but note that the form will not function properly, the wrong month will be checked.

General conclusion: don't mix EditForm with a for-loop. `foreach()` is safe.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it!

Comment: This is still the working solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a `foreach` statement in this case :

```cs
@foreach(var month in _months)
{
    <ul>
        <li><label for="@month.MonthId">@month.MonthName</label></li>
        <li><InputCheckbox id="@month.MonthId" @bind-Value="@month.IsMonthChecked" /></li>
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<Month> _months;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _months = new List<Month>
        {
            new Month{ MonthId = 0, MonthName = "All Months", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 1, MonthName = "Jan", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 2, MonthName = "Feb", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 3, MonthName = "Mar", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 4, MonthName = "Apr", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 5, MonthName = "May", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 6, MonthName = "Jun", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 7, MonthName = "Jul", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 8, MonthName = "Aug", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 9, MonthName = "Sep", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 10, MonthName = "Oct", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 11, MonthName = "Nov", IsMonthChecked = false },
            new Month{ MonthId = 12, MonthName = "Dec", IsMonthChecked = false }
        };
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```