# Dynamic Text Field Creation with Values in Blazor App

Tags: dynamic, data-binding, textbox, blazor

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8To79.png)  [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhPA5.png)

```
 @page "/"

@using UDemo.Data


@for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
{
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" @bind-value="@text_val" /> <p>@i</p><p>@count</p>

    </div>

}
<div class="row">

    <button @onclick=@(() => Increment())>Add User</button>

</div>


@code {
    private List<string> listItems = new List<string>();
    private string newItem;
    public string select_val;
    public string text_val;
    public int count = 1;
    public void Increment()
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }

}
```

- In this Code am trying to get Dynamic Text box with values. Don't know how to hold Dynamic text box values. Here i used two Way data Binding @bind-value.Is there any other way to solve this issue. *

Comment: I change the `@functions` to `@code`.Result:If i type in one text box ,its reflected in all text when added dynamically because of Two way data Binding.

Comment: Updated code with Expected output Image

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the image output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to bind to `userNames[i]`. And that is why a `foreach()` won't work here.

```
@page "/"

<ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < userNames.Count; i++)
    {
        int j = i;  // copy i to be safe

        <li>
        <input type="text" @bind="@userNames[j]"  />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<button @onclick="AddUser">Add User</button>


@*to verify  the binding*@
@foreach (string userName in userNames)
{
    <p>@userName</p>
}

@code
{

    List<string> userNames = new List<string>() { "first user" };

    void AddUser()
    {
        userNames.Add("");
    }

}
```

The `j = i` part is needed here and always a good practice when working with for loops and Blazor.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846385/60761) and do note the `[j]`.

Comment: now i can add user , how to retrieve user text box values when submit the data

Comment: They are in `userNames`. In this answer at least.

Comment: we are adding empty string each-time in the list,after enter the value how to retrieve data of each and every text-box what we added.

Comment: You're right, there is no proper 2-way binding yet.

Comment: Added the fix  (`@bind`) and a demo piece to verify.

Comment: without using initial value like List<string> userNames = new List<string>() { "first user" }; ,how to do the same problem statement

Comment: It's not entirely what you want, use `new List<string>();` for an empty screen (must click Add first) or with `new List<string>{ "" };` for 1 empty textbox.

Comment: When i remove {" "},1st box not appeared ,but am getting this error: Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions in 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'. when page was render

Comment: It's  `()` or  `{""}`. I can't read that error from here, you'll have to get it somehow.

Comment: Is there other way to get same output