# How to switch between read and edit mode for items of list in Blazor Client (razor component) .Net Core

Tags: razor, .net-core, blazor

I am trying to show a list of items (logs) as read-only when user clicks on edit button of an item that item (with ites properties) become editable. But one I click on edit icon of any item only the last one becomes editable. The delete action works fine and deletes the desired item.

```
                @{ int i = -1; }
                @foreach (var log in logs.OrderBy(p => p.Date))
                {
                    i++;
                <tr>
                    <td>@log.StaffId   @i</td>
                    <td>@log.StudyId</td>
                    @if (!isEditable[i])
                    {
                        <td>@log.Date.ToString("dd MMM")</td>
                        <td>@log.Hour</td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="oi oi-pencil" @onclick="(() => { isEditable[i] = true; })" />
                            <span class="oi oi-trash" @onclick="(() => Delete(log.Id))" />
                        </td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td><input type="date" @bind="@log.Date" /></td>
                        <td><input type="number" @bind="@log.Hour" /></td>
                        <td><span class="oi oi-cloud-upload" @onclick="(() => isEditable[i] = false)"/></td>

                    }
                </tr>
                }
```

in the above code isEditable is an helper array for switching between edit and read-only. It defined as

```
@code {

            bool[] isEditable;
protected async Task GetAll()
            {
                    logs = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Log>>($"api/Logs/{from.Ticks}/{to.Ticks}");
                    isEditable = new bool[logs.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < logs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        isEditable[i] = false;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new var inside the loop on each iteration:

```
@foreach (var log in logs.OrderBy(p => p.Date))
{
   i++;
   var j=i; // use j from now
   ...
   @if (!isEditable[j]) // like this
```

This is not a Blazor issue, it's about C#.

Comment: Yes, and it's called "capturing the loop var". Als see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59028857/60761

Answer (score 1):

You should define a local variable immediately at the beginning of the foreach loop into which you should assign the value of the i variable:

```
i++;
var local = i;
```

Now, at the code below replace i with the local modifier.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812427/for-loop-not-returning-expected-value-c-sharp-blazor/54813295#54813295) where I explain the cause of this...

Comment: Voted up. Your linked post was helpful too.