# Accessing properties in dynamic elements

Tags: dynamic, textbox, blazor, property-binding

With the reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027615/dynamic-text-field-creation-with-values-in-blazor-app), I am trying to add components dynamically. I could able to render those but all I need is to affect the property values of those components and that too in a dynamic manner. In my case, I am validating each input and add classes to those inputs accordingly in blur event.

I know I can achieve this by affecting the variable bound to the class property. But I could not figure out how to get the specific element to change the class in the blur handler.

This is what I have tried.

```
    <ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < userNames.Count; i++)
    {
        int j = i;  // copy i to be safe

 

        <li>
            <input type="text" class="@userNames[j]"  @onblur="onblur" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

 

<button @onclick="AddUser">Add User</button>

 


@*to verify  the binding*@
@foreach (int userName in userNames)
{
    <p>@userName</p>
}

 

@code
{

 

    List<int> userNames = new List<int>() { 0 };

 

    public int count = 0;
    void AddUser()
    {
        count++;
        userNames.Add(count);
    }
    public void onblur(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.FocusEventArgs args)
    {
      // Here I want to validate the correspoding input based on value and update the class property of the respective element.
    }
}
```

I also want to try the same using RenderFragment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.