# How to use RadioButtons and Checkboxes in an asp.net Blazor page

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I found it surprisingly difficult to dynamically create and use Radio Buttons and Checkboxes in an asp.net Blazor (Server-side) page, mostly because:

- I could not figure out how to bind in a `<input type="radio">` field
- I came across the `EditForm` rather late
- I did not find (m)any examples
- one has to use a *loop-local variable* to avoid closures (and index out of bound errors)
- `<InputCheckbox>` seems to be *unable* to bind to a `List<bool>` and a list of complex objects is required and throws an `ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a InstanceMethodCallExpression1 which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.` error.

So I am posting this question and answering it at the same time with a working solution. The following code first demonstrates the use of regular `<input>` fields and later uses the `EditForm` component. As far as I can tell, the latter one is the preferred solution.

I still have one question: How can one use a `List<bool>` instead of a list of complex objects? It just doesn't feel right having to use a separate class to encapsulate a singe property. It also complicates things if `formModel` is persisted using EF Core. The same issue was discussed in a similar context e.g. [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12000).

Answer (score 3):

I think your answer over complicates this.

The code below demonstrates a basic setup (it's demo code not production).

It uses the `EditForm` with a model.  There are radio buttons and checkboxes linked into a model that get updated correctly.  `Selected` has a setter so you can put a breakpoint in ans see who's being updated.

```cs
@page "/"
@using Blazor.Starter.Data

<EditForm EditContext="this.editContext">

    @foreach (var model in models)
    {
        <h3>@model.Value</h3>

        <h5>Check boxes</h5>
        foreach (var option in model.Options)
        {
            <div>
                <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="option.Selected" />@option.Value
            </div>
        }
        <h5>Option Select</h5>
        <div>
            <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="model.Selected">
                @foreach (var option in model.Options)
                    {
                    <div>
                        <InputRadio Value="option.Value" /> @option.Value
                    </div>
                    }
            </InputRadioGroup>
            <div>
                Selected: @model.Selected
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</EditForm>
<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="OnClick">Check</button>

@code {

    private EditContext editContext;

    private List<Model> models;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        models = Models;
        editContext = new EditContext(models);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = true;
    }

    public List<Model> Models => new List<Model>()
    {
        new Model() { Value = "Fred"},
        new Model() { Value = "Jon"},
     };


    public class ModelOptions
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Selected
        {
            get => _Selected;
            set
            {
                _Selected = value;
            }
        }
        public bool _Selected;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Selected { get; set; }
        public List<ModelOptions> Options { get; set; } = new List<ModelOptions>()
        {
            new ModelOptions() {Value="Tea", Selected=true},
            new ModelOptions() {Value="Coffee", Selected=false},
            new ModelOptions() {Value="Water", Selected=false},

        };
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Your solution is not so much different. You also bind the checkboxes to a bool residing in a list of complex objects (`List<ModelOptions>`) and not to a `List<bool>` directly. So your model class too contains a second class `ModelOptions`, which is not so elegant.

Comment: When I first looked at your answer I got lost on the detail and length - I think a lot of others will to - hence my comment on over complicates .  I've just gone thro it and yes not so different.

Comment: Well, for an easy answer I would not create an `EditContext` manually but pass the model class to the `EditForm`.

Comment: [Polite] Move on man, don't post if your not prepared for others to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example mentioned in the question with more detailled comments. First the version without `EditForm`, which is not the recommended way, but nicely demonstrates the closure problem and why a loop-local variable is required. It also demonstrates my failure to use an `<input>` field of `type="radiobutton"` as it seems impossible to bind a value to it:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Use Checkboxes and Radio Buttons in asp.net Blazor w/o EditForm</h1>

<h2>Checkboxes using a for-loop and a List of bool</h2>
Don't tick the left column, as it generates an index out of bounds error.
@for (int i = 0; i < CheckboxList.Count(); i++)
{
    // Gotcha: This is a closure, so the function call is stored together with the environment.
    // Since i resides outside of the loop, it is a single variable which is stored with the function call, so
    // index out of bound occurs because the last value is used. Instead, use a local variable, so for each
    // iteration, a new variable is used and bound to the function. This is a compiler gotcha.
    // Since C# 5.0, the loop variable of a foreach lop is inside the loop, so using foreach is save, but it
    // does not work with a List<bool> but requires a List of objects than contains a bool as in
    // foreach(bool items in CheckboxList), item is the iteration variable and cannot be assigned.
    // https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843339/getting-argumentoutofrangeexception-using-for-loop-in-blazor-component
    int ii = i;

    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" @bind=@CheckboxList[i] /><!-- does not work, index out of range -->
        <input type="checkbox" @bind=@CheckboxList[ii] />
        <label>Answer @ii</label>
    </div>
}
Checkbox selection for-loop: @OutTextCheckboxFor
<hr />


<h2>Checkboxes using a foreach-loop and a List&lt;Item&gt;</h2>
@foreach (CheckboxItem item in CheckboxItems)
{
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" @bind=@item.IsChecked />
        <label>@item.Title</label>
    </div>
}
Checkbox selection foreach-loop: @OutTextCheckboxForEach
<hr />



<h2> Does not work: Radio Buttons using a foreach-loop and a List&lt;Item&gt;</h2>
Somehow it seems as if binding a radio button does not work the same way as binding a checkbox. I would expect
that item.Ischecked is true/false, depending on the selection of the radio button.
@foreach (RadioItemBool item in RadioItems)
{
    <div class="form-check">
        @* would need to add value=, but can't as it is already assigned by bind?? *@
        <input type="radio" @bind=@item.IsChecked />
        <label>@item.Title</label>
    </div>
}
Radio selection foreach-loop: @OutTextRadioForEach
<hr />

<button @onclick="OnSubmit">
    Evaluate all the above
</button>
<hr />


@code {

    // could also use an array as a direct replacement for the list
    // could also be a field instead of a property
    public List<bool> CheckboxList { get; set; } = new List<bool> { true, false, true };

    public List<CheckboxItem> CheckboxItems = new List<CheckboxItem>() {
        new CheckboxItem(true, "Checkbox 1"), new CheckboxItem(false, "Checkbox 2"), new CheckboxItem(true, "Checkbox 3") };

    public List<RadioItemBool> RadioItems = new()
    {
        new RadioItemBool(false, "Radio 1"),
        new RadioItemBool(false, "Radio 2"),
        new RadioItemBool(false, "Radio 3")
    };


    string OutTextCheckboxFor;
    string OutTextCheckboxForEach;
    string OutTextRadioForEach;


    public class CheckboxItem
    {
        public bool IsChecked;
        public string Title;
        public CheckboxItem(bool isChecked, string title)
        {
            IsChecked = isChecked;
            Title = title;
        }
    }

    public class RadioItemBool
    {
        public bool IsChecked;
        public string Title;
        public RadioItemBool(bool isChecked, string title)
        {
            this.IsChecked = isChecked;
            this.Title = title;
        }
    }


    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        OutTextCheckboxFor = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < CheckboxList.Count(); i++)
        {
            OutTextCheckboxFor += " " + (CheckboxList[i] ? "1" : "0");
        }

        OutTextCheckboxForEach = "";
        foreach (CheckboxItem item in CheckboxItems)
        {
            OutTextCheckboxForEach += " " + (item.IsChecked ? "1" : "0");
        }

        OutTextRadioForEach = "";
        foreach (RadioItemBool item in RadioItems)
        {
            OutTextRadioForEach += " " + (item.IsChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the preferred version with `EditForm`, also demonstrating data validation for a text input. It also shows that it seems impossible to bind the checkboxes to a list of simple types (`List<bool>`) and a list of a complex type (`List<myBool>`) is required to prevent the `ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a InstanceMethodCallExpression1 which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.` exception (c.f. [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12000)). Often, the text shown in the checkboxes might also be stored in the separate class (`myBool`), but to demonstrate the shortcoming of not beeing able to bind to a list  of bool, only the `bool` is inside a separte class.

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<h2>EditForm input with validation</h2>
@* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation *@
<EditForm Model="@formModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="ShortText" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Short Text</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <InputText @bind-Value="formModel.ShortText" class="form-control" id="ShortText" aria-describedby="ShortTextHelp"
                       placeholder="Enter short text" />
            <small id="ShortTextHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is a required field.</small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Checkboxes" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Checkbox</label>
        <div id="Checkboxes" class="col-sm-10">
            @for (int i = 0; i < formModel.IsCheckedComplex.Count; i++)
            {
                // prevent closures (IsCheckedComplex[ii] needs to be a loop-local variable)
                int ii = i;

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @* Unfortunately, using @bind-value with a List<bool> does not work (see comment below *1) *@
                    <InputCheckbox class="form-check-input" id="@ii" @bind-Value="@formModel.IsCheckedComplex[ii].IsChecked" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for=@ii>"Text for item"</label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="RadioButtons" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Radio buttons</label>
        <div id="RadioButtons" class="col-sm-10">
            <InputRadioGroup id="RadioButtons" @bind-Value=@formModel.SelectedRadio>
                @foreach (var item in formModel.RadioItems)
                {
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <InputRadio class="form-check-input" id=@item.Index Value=@item.Index />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for=@item.Index>@item.Title</label>
                    </div>
                }
            </InputRadioGroup>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Inspect formModel in HandleValidSubmit() to see user inputs.</p>

</EditForm>

@code {

    private FormModel formModel = new();

    public class FormModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Short Text is too long.")]
        public string ShortText { get; set; }


        // === for the checkboxes

        // unfortunately, binding to a List<bool> is not possible; try replacing IsCheckedComplex with IsChecked above *1
        public List<bool> IsChecked { get; set; } = new() { true, false, false };
        public List<myBool> IsCheckedComplex { get; set; } = new() { new(true), new(false), new(false) };


        // a complex object is required as using List<bool> directly, throws an ArgumentException: The provided expression
        // contains a InstanceMethodCallExpression1 which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member
        // accessors (fields, properties) of an object. See e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12000
        public class myBool
        {
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

            // store the text shown in the checkbox items here as well

            public myBool(bool init)
            {
                IsChecked = init;
            }

        }


        // === for the radio buttons

        public int SelectedRadio = 2;

        public class RadioItem
        {
            public int Index;
            public string Title;
            public RadioItem(int index, string title)
            {
                this.Index = index;
                this.Title = title;
            }
        }

        public List<RadioItem> RadioItems = new()
        {
                new RadioItem(1, "Radio 1"),
                new RadioItem(2, "Radio 2"),
                new RadioItem(3, "Radio 3")
        };
    }

    
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // HandleValidSubmit called
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to not need the long explanation, you can replace `@for (int i = 0; i < CheckboxList.Count(); i++)` with `@foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, CheckboxList.Count()))`  and omit `int ii = i`

Comment: Yes, since C# 5.0 `foreach` uses a loop-local variable and one does not need `int ii=i` as explained [here](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/).