# Cannot increase the counter inside a for loop

Tags: c#, web, blazor-webassembly

```
<div class="forecast-list">
    @for (int i=1; i<13;i++)
    {
         <div style="position:relative;left:@onScreenPosition;">@CalcRevenuesChange(Incomes[i].Quantity,Forecast[i].Quantity) </div>
            onScreenPosition += 2;

    }
</div>
```

the counter still remains 0, I tried to increase him inside `@CalcRevenuesChange()` but still doesn’t work. The output that I expected for is:
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0   0  0  0  0

but it's still remains 0000000000000
........................................

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843339/getting-argumentoutofrangeexception-using-for-loop-in-blazor-component and may other questions by searching "Blazor For loop"

Comment: But the for-loop is Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables created inside element will always be reset. Try this.

```
 @{
        int count=1;
        <div class="forecast-list">
            @for (; count<13;count++)
            {
                 <div style="position:relative;left:@onScreenPosition;">@CalcRevenuesChange(Incomes[count].Quantity,Forecast[count].Quantity) </div>
                    onScreenPosition += 2;
        
            }
        </div>
}
```