# Dynamically add FluentTextField with a FluentButton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

In a Blazor application, I have a variable of type `List<string>`.

I would like to dynamically add a `<FluentTextField>` that binds to a `string` in the `List` every time an Add button is clicked.

Here's what I have so far

```
<FluentButton Label="Add" OnClick="AddTextField" />

@foreach (var text in _stringValues)
{
    <FluentTextField @bind-Value="text"></FluentTextField>
}
```

Code-behind:

```
private List<string> _stringValues;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _stringValues = new List<string>
}

private void AddTextField()
{
    _stringValues.Add(string.Empty);
}
```

C# is complaining that you can't change the value of text while it's in a foreach loop. I'm looking for feedback on my approach, not necessarily the code I've presented.

My question is: how does one create dynamic text fields on Blazor/Razor in response to changes in a `List<string>`?

Answer (score 0):

> C# is complaining that you can't change the value of text while it's
> in a foreach loop. I'm looking for feedback on my approach, not
> necessarily the code I've presented.

Well, Changing the text variable within the loop actually changes the reference of the object being iterated over and it's leading to the error we cannot do that.

> How does one create dynamic text fields on Blazor/Razor in response to
> changes in a List?

In order to create dynamic text fields, we have two ways to add dynamic `<FluentTextField>` elements with a `<FluentButton>` in Blazor while binding to a `List<string>`

Way 1:

In your AddTextField method, instead of modifying the existing item, add a new string with an empty value to the `_stringValues`. You can do like below:

```
private void AddTextField()
{
  _stringValues.Add(string.Empty);
}
```

**Note:** AddTextField ensures the loop iterates over the initial elements, while the newly added empty element will render after the loop.

Way 2:

Alternatively, instead of directly binding the text variable, introduce an index variable within the foreach loop. For instance, We can do that like below:

Your HTML code should be:

```
@foreach (var text in _stringValues)
{
  <FluentTextField @bind-Value="_stringValues[index]"></FluentTextField>
}
```

C#:

Within the  C# code, do as following:

```
private int index = 0;

private void AddTextField()
{
  _stringValues.Insert(index++, string.Empty);
}
```

**Note:** According to above code snippet, we are using the index to track the specific element associated with each `<FluentTextField>`, even after adding new items

Both ways would implements the dynamic creation of text fields without modifying the reference within the loop. You can use either of above steps. Make sure you have check any additional validation based on your scenario and requirement.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-8.0) if you want to know more about [blazor dynamic rendering.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: This is why ChatGPT is banned.

Comment: Yeah, it has all the answer and mostly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem like you. I solved it using a for-loop, like so:

```
<FluentButton Label="Add" OnClick="AddTextField" />
@for (int i = 0; i < _stringValues.Count; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
        <FluentTextField Label="Text" @onchange="(e) => UpdateStringValue(j, e.Value.ToString())" @bind-Value="@_stringValues[j]" />
        <FluentButton @onclick="() => RemoveValue(j)" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove</FluentButton>
    </FluentStack>
}
```

And then in your code-block:

```
@code{
   private List<string> _stringValues = new List<string>();
   async Task AddTextField() => _stringValues.Add(string.Empty);
   async Task UpdateStringValue(int i, string value) => _stringValues[i] = value;
   async Task RemoveValue(int i) => _stringValues.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Note the var j = i;
This was to solve ArgumentOutOfRange exceptions I kept getting. See [Getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException using for loop in Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843339/getting-argumentoutofrangeexception-using-for-loop-in-blazor-component/58846385#58846385)

I think that should solve your problem. Mine is slightly different, so I adjusted my code to fit your purpose.